# make panel scrollable in accordion using netzke

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netzke

I have a netzke application, with a sidebar and a main area. In the main area I show a map. In the sidebar I have an accordion. In the accordion I have a menu, and when clicking on a menu-item, I dynamically load the grid for that item in another panel of the accordion and open that panel.

That works, but the grid is not fitted to the panel in the y-direction, and there is no scrollbar. This means I lose the bottom part with the pagination and such. Pretty important :)

My accordion:

```
class NavigationAccordion < Netzke::Basepack::Accordion


  component :navigator do |c|
    c.workspace_id = [js_id, "workspace"].join("__")
  end

  def configure(c)
    c.active_tab = 0
    c.prevent_header = true
    c.items = [ {:title => "Search"}, :navigator, {:title => 'Data', :id => 'list_panel'}, {:title => 'Settings'}]
    super
  end

end
```

The navigator contains the menu, and in the mixed in javascript I have the following:

```
{
    rootVisible: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();

        this.on('render', function() {
            this.listPanel = Ext.ComponentManager.get("list_panel");
        }, this);


        this.on('itemclick', function(view, r, item, index, e) {
            var component = r.raw.cmp;

            this.netzkeLoadComponent(component, {container: "list_panel", callback: function(cmp) {
                this.listPanel.setTitle(cmp.title);
                this.listPanel.autoScroll = true;
                cmp.autoScroll = true

            }, scope: this});

            this.listPanel.expand();
        });
    },
```

As you can see I tried to play with the auto-scroll. The grid fits, but it doesn't scroll.
So I can never reach the bottom (with the pagination links etc.)

Screenshot:

[image]

UPDATE:

I tried to dynamically add the loaded component to the accordion, instead of adding as the contents of a panel in the accordion. I failed to do that, instead overwriting the complete accordion (I gave the id of the accordion as container --so I guess that makes sense :). But then the grid is rendered completely correct. Not sure if it possible, with `netzkeLoadComponent` to dynamically add a new panel to an accordion.

UPDATE 2: Dynamically added a panel to the accordion with same effect.

I was able to manually add a panel, and then added the grid to it, but it looks the same.

```
    this.on('itemclick', function(view, r, item, index, e) {
        var component = r.raw.cmp;

        var accordion = Ext.ComponentManager.get("application_container__application__navigation_accordion");
        var p = new Ext.panel.Panel({title: 'XXX'});
        accordion.items.add(p);

        this.netzkeLoadComponent(component, {container: p, callback: function(cmp) {
            //this.listPanel.setTitle(cmp.title);
        }, scope: this});

        p.expand();
```

But technically speaking, I am also doing the same. So :( :(

UPDATE 2: If I do not explicitly give a container to the `netzkeLoadComponent`, the grid is rendered correctly in the accordion, but it replaces the `this` (which is the navigator-tree). Sooooo ... it is possible. Now to find the correct set of events to do the rendering correctly.

This got me to thinking the panel where I want to place the grid, is hidden, and has no layout yet. I tried to make sure the `listPanel` was expanded first, did and explicit `doLayout` of the panel, did the `netzkeLoadComponent` after the passing of a timeout, but all to avail. I am close, but still no cigar :)

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. The crucial thing was to declare the dummy `list_panel` as a real panel, with a layout to fit.

So my accordion code became:

```
class NavigationAccordion < Netzke::Basepack::Accordion


  component :navigator do |c|
  end

  def configure(c)
    c.active_tab = 0
    c.prevent_header = true
    c.items = [ {:title => "Search"}, 
                :navigator, 
                {:title => 'Data', :id => 'list_panel', :xtype => 'panel', :layout => 'fit'},
                {:title => 'Settings'}
              ]
    super
  end
end
```

and then the click function on my treepanel became:

```
initComponent: function() {
  this.callParent();

  this.on('render', function() {
    this.listPanel = Ext.ComponentManager.get("list_panel");
  }, this);

  this.on('itemclick', function(view, r, item, index, e) {
    var component = r.raw.cmp;

    this.listPanel.expand();

    this.netzkeLoadComponent(component, {container: this.listPanel, callback: function(cmp) {
        this.listPanel.setTitle(cmp.title);
    }, scope: this});
  });
},
```

Now it works, dead easy, took me a while to find though :)